# Why are my Excel links to sheets within same document language-dependent?

Tags: excel

I have to maintain several Excel tools. For user convenience, I added hyperlinks to relevant sheets within a document. However, several users reported those links to not work - And bafflingly, the reason seems to be the difference in language settings.

Links only work when the Office Display Language is the same as when the document was created. If it is different, Excel complains that the **"Reference isn't valid."**

How can I change those links that they will work regardless of the language setting by the user?

[image: Excel links dependent on display language]

Comment: How did you create the links exactly?

Comment: Right-click the cell -> Hyperlink, select "Place in This Document", place the cell reference to the relevant sheet

Comment: Are there any personal macros that may be modifying that workbook sheets names?

Comment: No, that was not it - I found the solution, and posted it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further tests I found out both the cause of this behaviour and how to remedy it.

The problem only arises if the link is created *while* the cell reference is set to **R1C1 reference style**.
It seems Excel saves the cell reference for hyperlinks verbatim, but does not translate them like it does in formulas. And the cell reference is language-dependent if Excel is set to **R1C1 reference style** (Options --> Formulas --> Working with formulas --> R1C1 Reference style) - Eg. A1 in English is R1C1, but in German it's Z1S1.

[image]

So here's the solution:

- If reference style is set to R1C1 style, change it
- Re-create the hyperlinks to other sheets
- Save the document
- If required, the refernce style can now be set back to R1C1 style.

Here's the test setup I used:

[image]